# Date part of DATETIME in LINQ

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

```
(from sms in db.sms
                where sms.NeedModeration == true && sms.ReplyStatus == "test" && **sms.date.Value == date**
                select new 
                 {
                     SMSID = sms.SmsID,
                     Body = sms.body,
                     Date=sms.date,
                     ReplyStatus = sms.ReplyStatus
                 }).AsEnumerable().Select(x=>new VMSMS{
                     SMSID=x.SMSID,
                     Body=x.Body,
                     Date= x.Date.Value,
                     ReplyStatus = x.ReplyStatus
                 })
```

Given code works properly but in where part i want to match the date part only of type DATETIME like

```
 sms.date.Value.Date == date.Date
```

but it doesn't works properly it shows me the following error

```
The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.
```

So can you please tell me how can i **extract Date part from DateTime** type **in LINQ**?

Here is sms ViewModel code....

```
public class VMSMS
{
    public long SMSID { get; set; }
    public string SMS { get; set; }
    public int? SPOID { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }        
    public bool? IsRead { get; set; }
    public string DoctorCode { get; set; }
    public string ReplyStatus { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: can you post a declaration of sms entity?

Comment: tnx frennky for u r interest sms is actully a viewmodel and i've put its code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have IgnoreDataMember on the Date property it will not be mapped in your model.

So your comparison needs to happen at the Linq-to-Object level after you've done your projection.

Comment: Thanks Stewart for your reply. I've tried to remove ignoreDataMember but still it's showing me that error.

Comment: Ok, I think that I must be getting confused, as asked by @frennky: can you post the declaration of the sms entity?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the help. At last i got the answer it should be done as

```
EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(sms.date.Value) == EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(date)
```

It will truncate the time from date time.